# How to remove Apps Tab from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, google-workspace

With the newest Chrome update, an "Apps" bookmark has been added on left hand side of the bookmarks.

But I don't need that (my Apps are just next to it - as direct links) and want to remove it again.

**How can I remove this bookmark again?**

[image]

Right-click does not work:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deselect the `Show apps shortcut` in the menu shown in your question.